# prove $\max\{x,y\} = (x+y+|x - y|)/2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

Prove the following, 
$\max\{x,y\}=(x+y+|x-y|)/2$

Attempt at the proof:  first off I started by separating the expression into the following, 
$(x+y)/2 + |x-y|/2 $ and noting that both of them are an expression for the midpoint of the two, and so adding them together will give a max.  I just need help putting this into words and making a formal proof.

Comment: The case $x\ge y$ gives $\frac12(x+y+\vert x-y\vert)=\frac12(x+y+x-y)=x=\max(x,y)$. The other case is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answer and the comment above are more technical. Here is a hand-wavey / geometrical approach: your expression splits into
$$
\frac{x+y}2+\frac{|x-y|}2
$$
which may be interpreted as starting at the midpoint between $x$ and $y$, and then moving an amount along the number line equal to half the distance between $x$ and $y$. This procedure will place you at the largest one.

Comment: This also provides an intuitive formula for the minimum: $\frac{x+y}{2}-\frac{|x-y|}{2}$.

Answer (score 5):

For a formal proof, it's easier to simply consider two cases: $x \le y$ and $y<x$.
Just calculate both sides in both cases and see that they are equal.